# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_meta' on string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chart.js

I have been able to draw bar chart, line chart using the static data in Chartjs.
But when I try to use the dynamically received data through some api, there are some error message show.
My code is:

```
//'myCanvas' is the id for the canvas, where chart has to be drawn
const CHART = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
var userData = {};
var dateArray = [];
var dataArray = [];

var barChartData = {
labels: dateArray,
datasets: {
    label: "users",
    fillColor: '#382765',
    data: dataArray
    }
};

var configure = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData
//I have removed the option part from here to make this post compact
};

window.barChart = new Chart(CHART, configure);
window.barChart.render();
//fillData is called from HTML form submission
function fillData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/v1/data',
        data: 'start=' + document.getElementById('start').value + '&end=' + document.getElementById('end').value,
        success: function dataGet(data) {
            userData = JSON.parse(data);
            dataParse();
        }
    });
    window.barChart.update();
}

function dataParse() {
    for(var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
        dateArray.push(new Date(userData[i].date));
        dataArray.push(userData[i].users);
         }
}
```

The error I am getting is like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_meta' on string 'users'
getDatasetMeta @ Chart.min.js:12
(anonymous function) @ Chart.min.js:12
o.each @ Chart.min.js:12
buildOrUpdateControllers @ Chart.min.js:12
initialize @ Chart.min.js:12
t.Controller @ Chart.min.js:12
t @ Chart.min.js:13
(anonymous function) @ main.js:48

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_meta' on string 'users'
getDatasetMeta @ Chart.min.js:12
isDatasetVisible @ Chart.min.js:12
(anonymous function) @ Chart.min.js:12
o.each @ Chart.min.js:12
getElementAtEvent @ Chart.min.js:12
a @ Chart.min.js:12eventHandler @ Chart.min.js:12
(anonymous function) @ Chart.min.js:12
t.events.(anonymous function) @ Chart.min.js:12

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The data you're passing in is inconsistent with the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-example-usage)

Could you try making `datasets` an array?

Also, try providing static data initially to allow the chart to initialize with some mock data.

Comment: `datasets` was supposed to be an array. Code works now. Thanks!!